# JSplitPane SetDividerLocation Problem

Tags: java, jsplitpane

I have a JSplitPane which when shown should split the pane by 50%.

Now on giving an argument of 0.5 (as suggested) to setDividerLocation, Java seems to treat it as a normal number instead of a percentage. As in, the divider, instead of going to the middle of the pane, is almost at the start of the left pane (the pane is vertically split).
Any work arounds?

Answer (score 28):

Am I missing something? There seem to be a lot of rather convoluted answers to this question... but I think a simple setResizeWeight(0.5) would solve the issue ... it's described in the [SplitPane Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html#divider)

Comment: Oh oops, I overlooked that in the comments. Thanks. Seems odd though the most popular answer didn't mention it... on a question that's 2 yrs old now.

Answer (score 17):

The setDividerLocation( double ) method only works on a "realized" frame, which means after you've packed or made the frame visible.

The setDividerLocation( int ) method can be used at any time.

Comment: Which is obviously understandable

Answer (score 8):

You can only set the split pane divider's location as a percentage when the split pane is visible. You can tap into the split pane owner's events to determine when its OK to set the divider's location. For example:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

  public MyFrame() {

    final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    // ... set up the split pane, and add to the frame ...

    // Listen for the frame's "shown" event.

    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void componentShown(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {

        // Set the divider location to 20%.
        // This works because we know the pane is visible.

        splitPane.setDividerLocation(.2);

        // Stop listening for "shown" events.

        removeComponentListener(this);
      }

    });

    pack();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this fixes it:

```
public class JSplitPane3 extends JSplitPane {
    private boolean hasProportionalLocation = false;
    private double proportionalLocation = 0.5;
    private boolean isPainted = false;

    public void setDividerLocation(double proportionalLocation) {
        if (!isPainted) {
            hasProportionalLocation = true;
            this.proportionalLocation = proportionalLocation;
        } else {
            super.setDividerLocation(proportionalLocation);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (!isPainted) {
            if (hasProportionalLocation) {
                super.setDividerLocation(proportionalLocation);
            }
            isPainted = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just for clarification I have gotten it to work using only paint() and no hasProportionalLocation if I specify it manually in the code. Much shorter than this monstrosity

Comment: Thanks.  Just came across this and it has been bugging us for ages. +1

Comment: I've always used this approach.  However, I've noticed that you do momentarily see the divider location in the wrong position before it is moved.  To resolve this, rather then overriding paint(Graphics) I have taken to overriding validate() instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy for the divider to move to the middle every time you resize the pane, you could add a ComponentListener and have its componentResized method call setDividerLocation(0.5).

Comment: You would use the setResizeWeight(...) method for this.

Answer (score 2):

use `setResizeWeight(double);`

Answer (score 2):

I found the combination of `setResizeWeight` and `setDividerLocation` invoked later provides the behavior one would expect:

```
_splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        _splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    }
});
```

Comment: Because such operation **must** be done in EDT.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, based on Dave Rays [link](http://blog.darevay.com/2011/06/jsplitpainintheass-a-less-abominable-fix-for-setdividerlocation/).

```
/**
 * Set JSplitPane proportional divider location
 * 
 * @param jsplitpane JSplitPane to set
 * @param proportionalLocation double <0.0; 1.0>
 */
public static void setJSplitPaneDividerLocation(final JSplitPane jsplitpane, final double proportionalLocation)
{
    if (jsplitpane.isShowing())
    {
        if (jsplitpane.getWidth() > 0 && jsplitpane.getHeight() > 0)
        {
            jsplitpane.setDividerLocation(proportionalLocation);
        }
        else
        {
            jsplitpane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce)
                {
                    jsplitpane.removeComponentListener(this);
                    setJSplitPaneDividerLocation(jsplitpane, proportionalLocation);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        jsplitpane.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e)
            {
                if ((e.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0 && jsplitpane.isShowing())
                {
                    jsplitpane.removeHierarchyListener(this);
                    setJSplitPaneDividerLocation(jsplitpane, proportionalLocation);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution [here](http://blog.darevay.com/2011/06/jsplitpainintheass-a-less-abominable-fix-for-setdividerlocation/) that is a simple function that doesn't require sub-classing or any other changes to your splitpane.

Answer (score 0):

The following in the `Component` with the `JSplitPane` does it too:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(final boolean b) {
    super.setVisible(b);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AppFrame.this.jSplitPane.setDividerLocation(0.9d);
        }

    });
}
```